# Retrieving collection size of a Cosmos DB collection in .NET

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there a nice way in .NET to retrieve the storage size of a Cosmos DB collection?

I know it's possible to look into the `x-ms-resource-usage` header, but that's a string that has to be parsed and whose format may be subject to change. In the old .NET client library you could obtain a [`ResourceResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.resourceresponse-1?view=azure-dotnet) object with all sorts of useful properties like `CollectionSizeUsage`. Is there an equivalent solution with the current library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PopulateQuotaInfo` option in the `ContainerRequestOptions` when reading a container.

```
ContainerRequestOptions cro = new ContainerRequestOptions();
cro.PopulateQuotaInfo = true;
ContainerResponse cr = await container.ReadContainerAsync(cro);
```

The information is present in the response `x-ms-resource-usage` header:

```
Headers headers = cr.Headers;
string usage = headers["x-ms-resource-usage"];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my question explicitly asked for a solution that does not involve parsing `x-ms-resource-usage`. But I suppose that means a more type-safe solution does not exist anymore in the current .NET SDK.

Comment: There is an internal `CosmosQuotaResponse` class in the source code with the property `ContainerSize`, but it's not in use anywhere. :-(

Comment: There is no public type as this is not currently a hard contract.